# Falling back / 3-way messages in rebase

Tags: git

When I rebase on the remote tracking branch for master, I get the following message

```
$ git rebase origin/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: 'XXX'
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
```

What does "patching base" mean here? Are 3-way merges done on a file by file basis? Is there any way to disable them?

Comment: You can [tell `git rebase` to use a different merge strategy in the case of conflicts by using the `-s` flag and specifying a strategy](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_merge_strategies).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git rebase merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709885/git-rebase-merge-conflict)

Answer (score 3):

It is a technical message, which shouldn't bother you.

The important thing is to see :

- if git tells you that there is a merge conflict : git will stop with an explicit message right afterwards,
- or if it managed to apply the changes and proceed : git will proceed with its regular progress messages until the "successfully rebased x ..." message appears.