# git bash rebase 1 of

Tags: git, git-bash

issue with git bash when trying to push.  I've tried the following (see code snippet) to pull the latest down before pushing but I get the following error (see screen shot).  How can I resolve this please?
Many thanks,

[image]

**code**

```
git pull --rebase
```

**Update**

See below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git rebase merge conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709885/git-rebase-merge-conflict)

Comment: When I try git mergetool it says "no files need merging"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - **that's not an error.**  Git is telling you that you've got 3 commits to rebase, and it's run into a conflict on the first one.

You **must** resolve the conflicts in the conflict, then add them to your index via `git add .`, *then* you can use `git rebase --continue`.

If you want to abandon the rebase and start over, use `git rebase --abort`.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the middle of a rebase?, try `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: have updated my question after trying your suggestion.

Comment: Do not say what is happening, but could you give more details about what you were doing when the error become, could be useful....

Comment: i wrote some code, did git add . followed by git commit -m 'bla' and then try pulling..  That's all

Comment: Do you mean specify the url?

Comment: You can se if have conflict by using "git status", if found solve this with your merguetool("git merguetool"). "git status" show conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below sequence,

```
git commit
git clean -f
git pull --rebase
                    |
                    | # resolve conflict, use mergetool
#only when conflict | git add
                    | git rebase --continue
                    |
git push
```