# Git conflict while merge/rebase

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-bash

I'm having git conflict while doing a rebase. I want to keep both the files from mine and theirs... Is there any way to resolve it and keep both the files?

Answer (score 0):

1. `git stash` your local change.
2. `git rebase`
3. `git stash pop` get your change
4. fix local conflict
5. push

Comment: Git stage, or git stash?

Comment: Well I have resolved it manually... First use mine and then use theirs... And I saved both the files

Comment: typo, stash, there is previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709885/git-rebase-merge-conflict

Answer (score 0):

You note that:

> I have resolved it manually...

In fact, *any* resolution is manual, by definition.  Git tried to resolve it automatically and failed, and stopped in the middle of the rebase.  Your job is to resolve the problem.  Whatever you do, Git assumes that's the right resolution. :-)  Whatever you did, you did "manually".

> First use mine and then use theirs... And I saved both the files

If you mean:

```
git checkout --ours path/to/file
cp path/to/file path/to/file.ours
git add path/to/file.ours
git checkout --theirs path/to/file
git add path/to/file
```

for instance, that's a correct way to keep the "ours" version under a new name and tell Git that `path/to/file` should use the the "theirs" version as the resolved file.

In any case, whatever you did, Git will *assume* that this is the correct resolution of the problem: when Git's automatic merge fails, Git relies on you to know the right answer.