# Why am I getting Could not Apply Remove dead code with Git Rebase

Tags: git

I am trying to squash the following commits 1,2,3,4 and 5. The rests of the commits are comming from the a merge of develop branch with my branch. I used the following command line:

```
git rebase -i d3c5321cbc3 (which is the commit right under 1f65fc141cd)

pick 1f65fc141cd WHERE I WANT TO SQUASH
s 881d49fe757 commit1
s 9c02d893697 commit2
s 6e146d89daa commit3
[...]
s fa4b6c3805e commit4
s 65f4969bc8f commit5
pick 8017df05f67 commit6
pick 31391e4d1d3 commit7
[...]
```

I don't understand why I am getting a dead code. And how can I fix it?

---

## Error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing what the message said, and checking for / resolving conflicts...? That isn't Git telling you to "Remove dead code"; it's Git saying that's the commit message of `2baaae7ca72`, which is the commit causing the issue. You can `git diff` the work tree to see why, and then edit/add/continue the rebase to resolve it.

Comment: @underscore_d Thank you for the question. I actually asked the question because I got so angry for having to fix the merge conflicts. the files where I got the conflicts are not mine. Why Is Git forcing me to do that?

Comment: Because it can't just guess what should happen if other devs have changed things in the same/near location as you... they wouldn't be very happy if it just made a call about how to make your changes 'win' and erased their work and broke the codebase, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why I am getting a dead code. And how can I fix it?

The error message is a bit confusing, what you see is in fact a Git conflict (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709885/git-rebase-merge-conflict) of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709885/git-rebase-merge-conflict)) and `Remove dead code` is simply the **commit message associated with commit `2baa...`** which cannot be rebased because of said conflict.

You do not have a "dead code" issue, that's simply some message associated to the conflicting commit.

You should:

- Resolve the conflict locally
- Run `git rebase --continue` once conflict is solved

Comment: what If i delete all the other lines with the pick ?

Comment: That's a choice you have to make depending the code you want to keep or not. A conflict mean that the branch you are trying to rebase on and your branch made conflicting changes on some file - you should either keep your changes, keep the other changes, or adapt the code to "merge" both of your changes