# Handling git rebase properly

Tags: git

I am working in a team where we use feature branch for our work. This is the model

1. there is a master branch
2. a developer cuts the feature branch from master branch and work on it
3. create a pull request(PR) from the feature branch once all changes are done
4. once PR is approved, get it merged to master (there is some webUI on this)

I started working on a feature branch by creating it from master around a month ago. In between several developers worked on some feature and those got merged to master.
Today when I tried to create the PR, I got an error message to resolve the conflict. This is what I did

```
1. git rebase origin/master
```

after I resolved the merge conflicts, this are the commands performed

```
git add .
```

Now when I run the command

```
git status
```

I see the following (features/branch-name|REBASE 1/1)

I am not sure what I should be doing next since doing
git rebase --continue is not helping.

I am still looking for solution but kind of not sure what should be done next. Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: If you encountered merge conflicts during the `rebase` command, you need to run `git rebase --continue` after `git add`.

Comment: If you read the entire message from `git status`, it will not only tell you the status, but also the commands necessary to proceed

Comment: @SwissCodeMen. I think you missed the part of the question where OP is trying to do just that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git rebase merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709885/git-rebase-merge-conflict)

Comment: Unfortunately no.. As I tried these options as well..

Comment: Please post the exact output of `git status` as well as `git log --graph --oneline head master origin/master`

Comment: I read some articles online and used the following (since there was nothing else left to resolve)

    `git rebase --skip` 
    `git push --force`

and see that REBASE 1/1 is no more there when using the command 

    `git status`

Comment: If the problem is solved please delete the question.

Comment: or preferably post an answer with your solution!

Comment: I answered so that it might be useful. I am wondering why negative voting on this question?

Comment: @Raman Don't wonder, it's pointless. No one knows who votes up/down and why. One must just accept that questions and answers on Stack Overflow are subject to votes.

Comment: @matt I fully agree that question/answer are subjected to votes. However I spent close to 5 hours reading various articles and when I did not find a definite answer, I posted my question. The only problem with downvoting of genuine questions is restrictions on activities for the question poser.

Comment: One downvote won't cause that. My advice is to stop worrying! It all comes out right in the end, generally speaking. It's the "wisdom of the crowd".

Answer (score 0):

I read some articles online and used the following (since there was nothing else left to resolve)

```
`git rebase --skip`
```

`git push --force`

and see that REBASE 1/1 is no more there when using the command git status